# Airline Program

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a program for an assignment in Java and are looking for a push in the right direction. I am currently taking the class online so asking a teacher for help is not an option for me.

I am trying to create a simple java program that allows a user to enter their first name and last name, and their requested seat number. If the seat is taken, the program is supposed to find the nearest available seat. So far I have succeeded at getting all the input from the user (albeit in a roundabout way) and creating and printing an array.

**Question**

Can I store `boolean` values in an array? I just want to store false if the seat is taken and then have and if else statement test for true or false, and store a false if the value returned is true(very confusing but thats my train of thought) is there an easier way to go about this? Also how would I also store the persons first and last name with that boolean value? Do I have to create a seperate array? I have attached my code so far that succeeds in getting the user info and printing out an array.

```
//Import scanner and arrays
    package airlinereservations;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class AirlineReservations {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Print the header
    System.out.println("___________________________________");
    System.out.println("|WELCOME TO FLY BY NIGHT AIRLINES!|");
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

    // Promt user for first and last name
    System.out.println("Please enter your first name:");

    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

    String first = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter your last name:");

    String last = scan.nextLine();
    //Greet the user
    System.out.println("Hello! " + first + " "+ last);
    //Get the requested seat
    System.out.println("Please enter your requested seat row number 1-9:");

    int rowz = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter your requested seat column number 1-4:");

    int colz = scan.nextInt();
    //Tell the user if the seat is already taken
    if(int rowz == rowz, System.out.println("This seat is already taken!"));
        else(return true);

     //Print out the array
    int[][] Seating= new int[9][4];

         for(int row=0; row<Seating.length; ++row){
        for(int col=0; col<Seating[row].length; ++col){
            Seating[row][col] = (row + col) % 9 + 1; 



        for(int ro=0; ro<Seating.length; ++ro);
             }
        System.out.println();
        for(int col=0; col<Seating [row].length; ++col) 
            System.out.print(Seating[row][col]);


        }
        System.out.println();



   }
   }
```

Comment: you can store pretty much anything you want in an array.

Comment: boolean[][] myArray=new boolean[5][6] is a 5 by 6 matrix of booleans

Comment: @RichardTingle How would I store a boolean value in a specific spot for example if I wanted to store false in column 4 row 2?

Comment: @MK4 the syntax would be like this: `myArray[1][3] = false`. Row is listed first, and then column, and of course, indexing starts at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a push in the right direction, as you said, I see two quick options to consider:

One would be to add a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). This would allow you to store a bunch of key-value pairs which you could use to represent seats, and whether or not they are taken.

Another option is to create a `Seat` class, that has a field for seatName and whether or not it is taken, and you could create an Array of these seat objects.

If you don't know where to begin on implementing either of those, I will help you, but I challenge you to at least try implementing one or the other first.

**EDIT**

Or, even more simply, you could create a two-dimensional array holding strings, like this:

```
String[][] seats = new int[numberofseats][2];
seats[0][0] = "Seat Number 1";
seats[0][1] = "true";
```

And you can force that second dimension to only hold values true or false, and later check them like this:

```
if(seats[0][1].equals("true")) // Then seat number 1 is taken
```

This might not be the best solution as far as error handling, but it is a possibility.

**EDIT 2** If you were to create a seat class, I would set it up like this:

```
public class Seat{
   private String seatName;
   private boolean isTaken;

   public Seat(String s, boolean t){
      this.seatName = s;
      this.isTaken = t;
   }

   public boolean isSeatTaken(){
      return this.isTaken;
   }
}
```

Then, later you can do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Seat> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Seat>(); // Or a regular array if you prefer
// Add elements
// Below checks if first seat in list is taken
boolean firstSeatTaken = myArrayList.get(0).isSeatTaken();
```

Comment: So for the seat class I would create a class that takes in a seat as it's parameter and returns a boolean? Would that be like public Seats(//requested seat) returns boolean

Comment: What does the this. Add to those variables, is that text it displays or?

Comment: Well, when you start, an ArrayList is empty, so you will need to input the seats somehow. Here's some ArrayList [examples](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/arraylist/arraylist-in-java-example-how-to-use-arraylist/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The list helps a ton, I decided to just print an array with the location of seats 1-36 and then have the user pick a number then check the list for true or false.

Comment: Ok so I have a few more questions, first is there an easier way to populate this list than adding each number individually, and second, how do I use the number the user entered to change that seat number and make it return false? It wont let me do 'list.set(requestedSeat, false);'

Comment: Well, if you have a set number of seats, you can do a regular array instead and declare the items all at once. To set a value, let's assume inside your class you have a `setIsTaken(boolean taken)` method (or something like it), you can call this to set the first seat to not taken: `myArrayList.get(0).setIsTaken(false);`

Comment: So then how can I substitute the user's variable for 0?

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your code looks like - look into how you can look up an array list item by value, or something like that.